# How make request post in angular?

Tags: java, angular, spring, ionic-framework

Currently I only do requests get from angular, as I do post request?

I have this code get

```
getUsers() {
        const url: string = "http://localhost:8080/user/getUsers/";
        return this.http.get<Object[]>(url);
    }
```

How Post request as I do?

I want to request this `const url: string = "/ meet / createMeetWithFriend";` but that url needs two id of  Users object

when I use this, it does not return anything

```
const url = 'http://localhost:8080/meet/createMeetWithFriend';
        return this.http.post(url, user.id, user.id); //two id user
```

this is the endpoint in spring

```
@PostMapping("/createMeetWithFriend")
    public ResponseEntity<Meet> createMeetWithFriend(@PathVariable("userOwner") Long idOwner, @PathVariable("user") Long idUser) {

        return new ResponseEntity<Meet>(meetService.createMeetWithFriend(idOwner, idUser), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

Comment: send all your necessary variables as one object and pass it in the post request with along with the url in the parameters of the post. ex) `return this.http.post(url, { user1: user1.id, user2: user2.id })` and so long as your endpoint is equipped to accept an object of this format, you are good to go.

Comment: FYI that's not a very RESTful API

Comment: @JamieTaylorSangerman Is there no problem with the spring endpoint?

Comment: @jonrsharpe what is the problem, why is not api resful?

Comment: The route is a verb, an action, not a noun, a thing. Also `@RequestParam` is for query parameters, not the request body.

Comment: @jonrsharpe i edited with PathVariable

Comment: Do you actually *want* them to be path parameters? Which side of this API do you think is right, and which one are you trying to fix?

Comment: @jonrsharpe 
Actually my question is directed to how to make a request Post from angular to spring

Comment: But how to make the right request depends on what the server expects. Angular doesn't care whether it's Spring or not, that's one of the points of separating concerns over an API boundary. Either way I'd strongly recommend reading the documentation (for both Spring and Angular) rather than random guessing: https://angular.io/guide/http#making-a-post-request

Comment: The "REST" comment is that your endpoint is not idiomatic; it should simply be named `/friends`, so that you `POST /friends` to create a new one, `GET /friends` to list them, `GET /friends/{id}` to get a specific one, `DELETE /friends/{id}`...

Answer (score 2):

You have to send your body as object i.e:

```
const url = 'http://localhost:8080/meet/createMeetWithFriend';
        return this.http.post(url, {userId: user.id, userId2: user.id });
```

Remember that you backend have to accept JSON as body, of your post request.

Comment: Is there no problem with the spring endpoint? can give an example for spring to effect the action in the controller