# Send data post in angular

Tags: angular

What is the problem, when i do try send dato from fronted to backend i get error 400, i not understanding what is the problem.

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse, HttpHeaders} from '@angular/common/http';


@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ListUserService {

    constructor(public http: HttpClient) {
        this.http.get(`http://localhost:8080/user/getUsers/`)
            .subscribe(response => {
                console.log(response);
            });
    }

addFriend(user) {
        const config = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json').set('Accept', 'application/json')
        const url = 'http://localhost:8080/meet/friend?idOwner=?&idUser=?';
        console.log('SS', user.id);
        const body = JSON.stringify({"idOwner": 89.9, "idUser": 89.9});

        return this.http.post(url, body, {headers: config}).subscribe(response => {
            console.log('jkljl', response);
        });
    }
    }
```

And this is the enpoint in spring -java, the endpoint need two parameters, a id-Owner and id-User

```
   @RequestMapping(
            value = "/friend/{idUser}/owner/{idOwner}",
            method = RequestMethod.POST
    )
    public ResponseEntity<Meet> friend(  @PathVariable Long idUser,@PathVariable Long idOwner) {
        log.info("PUSEN " +idOwner+"   "+idUser);
        return new ResponseEntity<Meet>(meetService.createMeetWithFriend(idOwner, idUser), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

i get this error:

```
019-05-24 14:30:18.518  WARN 9840 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound             : No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/meet/friend] in DispatcherServlet with name
'dispatcherServlet'
```

Comment: `@RequestParam` is [**still**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56283051/how-make-request-post-in-angular#comment99180488_56283051) for query parameters, **not** the request body.

Comment: @jonrsharpe 
Should I change it? I do not know what to put in place

Comment: You should change one side or the other, because they currently don't match up, but we can't tell you which. When you decide what the API should actually be, the [Spring Boot docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/) can help you implement it. I also rate https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot

Comment: @jonrsharpe i edited my question with endpoint in spring java

Comment: So you want the data to be in the path? Because **you're not doing that either**. For the final time: the client request has to correspond with what the server expects. It's unreasonable to expect it to work unless that's the case. Pick an API, then **write *both sides* to that**.

Comment: @jonrsharpe i have problem with url in angular

Comment: Alright now I just have to assume you're trolling. Best of luck.

Answer (score 2):

As you are making a post to your Spring Boot application, you need to make some adjusts in you Spring Rest Controller.

The @RequestParam is used to get query param from the URL, e.g.: meet/friend? idOwner=1&idUser=2 which is not your case. You need to receive as RequestBody.

I suggest you to create a simple Java Pojo class which will contain just the fields you are intent to receive, e.g:

```
public class Friend {
    public Long id1;
    public Long id2;

   // Getters and Setters
}
```

Then, you change your method in java controller to receive this new class, eg.:

```
public ResponseEntity<Meet> friend(@RequestBody Friend friend) {
    // Log what you need here
    return new ResponseEntity<Meet>(meetService.createMeetWithFriend(friend.getId1(), friend.getId2()), HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Pay attention to the name of the attributes of the pojo class which must match the names of the json attributes you are Stringfy in angular.

Comment: i not want create pojo, please

Comment: i get this erro 019-05-24 14:30:18.518  WARN 9840 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound             : No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/meet/friend] in DispatcherServlet with name
'dispatcherServlet'

Comment: @noseJ You can receive through the URL as you changed but now you will have to change your angular too. Your angular code is posting a body to /meet/friend and your Spring controller expect to receive the parameters like /meet/friend/1/owner/2 . As you can see the URL is not matching. If you want to keep your Spring controller this way you will have to change your angular code to send the ids in the same pattern of the Spring controller.

Comment: i edited my question, how to change the url? i have problems with url